# How to install Percona XtraDB Cluster on x86 server?

Tags: mysql, replication, centos5, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'm going to migrate from MySQL replication to [Percona XtraDB Cluster](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster). The problem I'm facing is one node is running on x86, and I cannot install `Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server` from the [Percona repo](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/installation/yum_repo.html) due to the depsolving problems:

```
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
1:Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-5.5.27-23.6.356.rhel5.i686 from percona has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-galera is needed by package 1:Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-5.5.27-23.6.356.rhel5.i686 (percona)
Error: Missing Dependency: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-galera is needed by package 1:Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-5.5.27-23.6.356.rhel5.i686 (percona)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

As you can see, `Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-galera` doesn't exist in the [repo](http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster/5.5.27-23.6/RPM/rhel5/i686/).

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why the `Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-galera` is missing from the Percona repo. But you can [compile from source code](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/installation/compiling_xtradb_cluster.html).

First, download and install [Galera wsrep provider](http://www.codership.com/downloads/download-mysqlgalera):

```
Name        : galera                       Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 23.2.1                            Vendor: Codership Oy
Release     : 1.rhel5                       Build Date: Sat 19 May 2012 04:16:24 AM ICT
Install Date: Mon 10 Sep 2012 05:22:01 PM ICT      Build Host: centos5_32builder.localdomain
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: galera-23.2.1-1.rhel5.src.rpm
Size        : 22430313                         License: GPLv3
Signature   : (none)
Packager    : Codership Oy
URL         : http://www.codership.com/
Summary     : Galera: a synchronous multi-master wsrep provider (replication engine)
Description :
Galera is a fast synchronous multimaster wsrep provider (replication engine)
for transactional databases and similar applications. For more information
about wsrep API see http://launchpad.net/wsrep. For a description of Galera
replication engine see http://www.codership.com.
```

Second, download the Percona-XtraDB-Cluster's [source code](http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster/5.5.27-23.6/source/) and install follow [this](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/installation/compiling_xtradb_cluster.html) guide. Notice that, since you're running x86, build binaries by running the following commands:

```
# cd Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-5.5.27
# BUILD/compile-pentium-wsrep
# make install
```

Third, change the `/etc/my.cnf` to something like this:

```
[mysqld]
# Percona XtraDB Cluster
binlog_format=ROW

wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

wsrep_slave_threads=2
wsrep_cluster_name=trimethylxanthine
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_node_name=node2

innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2


[mysqld_safe]
wsrep_urls=gcomm://192.168.1.100:4567, \
           gcomm://192.168.1.200:4567, \
           gcomm://192.168.1.300:4567, \
           gcomm://
```

Don't forget to adjust the init script `/etc/init.d/mysql` to point to the corresponding MySQL binary:

```
if test -z "$basedir"
then
  basedir=/usr
  #bindir=/usr/bin
  bindir=/usr/local/mysql/bin
  if test -z "$datadir"
  then
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
  fi
  sbindir=/usr/sbin
  libexecdir=/usr/sbin
else
...
```